# Can one website have two different hosting connections?

Tags: rtmp

I have one website say social network hosted on BlueHost.  THen i need a RTMP hosting server to enable live video chat.  Bluehost doesn't provide it.  Is it possible i can host the video chat part on another service that runs RTMP and connect the two sites?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can freely embed information from another server to your main site.

Depending on implementation, you probably have to host the Flash stream player on the same server that is hosting the RTMP. This is because the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) controls what servers the Flash applet can connect to.

The easiest solution may be to use an iframe to embed the video chat.